# Inline juqery syntax error

Tags: jquery, html

Inside a .php page i have a function.Inside that function, some of my code looks like the following:-

```
$html='';
$html.='<div id="imgContainer"></div>';
$html.='<img  src="elements/18_lr.jpg"  data-highres="elements/18_hr.jpg" onclick="$(this).mbZoomify({screen:'#imgContainer'});">';//<<----shows error near #imgContainer
```

At the above indicated line, it shows incorrect HTML error.Please advise how to get rid of the error.

Comment: as you can see in your post highlight, one `'` is not escaped properly

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to mis-matching quotes. You need to escape the `'` within the object value, like this:

```
$html.='<img src="elements/18_lr.jpg" data-highres="elements/18_hr.jpg" onclick="$(this).mbZoomify({ screen:\'#imgContainer\' });">';
```

*However*, a much better solution entirely would be to remove the outdated and ugly `on*` event attribute completely and use unobtrusive event handlers. As you've already included jQuery in the page, here's how you can do that:

```
$html.='<img src="elements/18_lr.jpg" data-highres="elements/18_hr.jpg" data-screen="#imgContainer" />';
```

```js
$('#container img').click(function() {
  $(this).mbZoomify({ 
    screen: $(this).data('screen');
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to do this, but personally I'd say the most readable by far is:

```
$html = <<<'END'
<div id="imgContainer"></div>
  <img src="elements/18_lr.jpg" data-highres="elements/18_hr.jpg" onclick="$(this).mbZoomify({screen:'#imgContainer'});">
END;
```

No escaping required!

Answer (score 0):

Use backword slash "\"

```
$html='';
$html.='<div id="imgContainer"></div>';
$html.='<img  src="elements/18_lr.jpg"  data-highres="elements/18_hr.jpg" onclick="$(this).mbZoomify({screen:\'#imgContainer\'});">';//<<----shows error near #imgContainer
```